# Get first and last value from array

Tags: javascript

I have a an array being passed to me which is something like

```
var arr = ["A", "B", "C"];
```

What I am trying to achieve is to only get the first and last value so it should look like

```
var arr = ["A", "C"];
```

I'm not how to achieve this using `splice` because when I do

```
arr.splice(I am not sure what numbers to put here).forEach(function (element) {
        console.log(element);
});
```

Can someone tell me how to achieve this please.

Comment: For first value use arr[0] and for last use  arr[arr.length - 1];

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What I am trying to achieve is to only get the first and last value so
>   it should look like

Simply

```
arr.splice( 1, arr.length - 2 );
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = ["A", "B", "C"];

arr.splice(1, arr.length - 2);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You've made it look so simple! Thanks, I will accept it as soon as the time limit is up

Comment: Why would it only give me one item if I do `arr.splice(1, arr.length - 2).forEach(function(element){console.log(element)})` prints out `B`

Comment: You are using the return value of splice, which are the deleted items rather than the items which are left in arr.

Comment: Oh right, can I not use it like that? Because I need to make changes to the original variable further down the line

Answer (score 1):

For the first element you know `arr[0]`
For the last element `arr[arr.length -1]`
so `let newAr = [arr[0], arr[arr.length -1]]`

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are trying to get values between the first and the last value of your array removed, you need to pass splice some value indicating how many elements your array contains.

this is why you should consider using:

```
var arr = ["A", "B", "C"];
arr.splice(1, arr.length - 2);
```

**Explanation:**

Splice takes at least 2 variables (this goes only if you use splice to remove items), the first being the position of the string at which you want to start removing items, and the second the number of items you actually want to remove.

To translate this simple line with words, it says 
After the first element of the array, remove the next X items with X being the length of the array minus the first and the last element (this is why you have the "-2").

Hope i explained properly,

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```js
var arr = ["A", "B", "C"];

console.log(arr.filter((e, i) => i==0 || i==arr.length-1));
```